# Phonegap: not able to install plugin in 3.5.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am not able to install Device plugin in my phonegap project getting the below error.

```
D:\JOB WORK\phonegap\Practice\deviceDetails>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-u
s.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
Fetching plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.g
it" via git clone
Error: Command failed: Cloning into 'C:\Users\TECHMA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\plugma
n\git\1407908234359'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-
device.git/': Failed connect to git-wip-us.apache.org:443; No error

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:647:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:968:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you are using Windows but the Device Plugin has support for iOS as well. 
By NOT specifying the platform in "cordova plugin add" command you are telling cordova to install the plugin for all platforms. This command fails because you can't install the iOS version of plugin on a Windows machine.

Solution: try adding the platform in command 

    cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git android

Comment: @UngureanuLiviu still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

What URL to install that plugin are u using there? The command is:

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device

Try that

Comment: It is not working, i tried it before also gives me an error Etimedout

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that you are using Windows but the Device Plugin has support for iOS as well. 
By NOT specifying the platform in "cordova plugin add" commad you are telling cordova to install the plugin for all platforms. This command fails because you can't install the iOS version of plugin on a Windows machine.

On solution could be appending the platform at the end of command.

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git android
```

(I can't test it right now but I used it some time ago)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not installing because of proxy, i installed via open internet. It worked perfectly.

Thanks All.